# Why is my Display method in the opengl class not working

Tags: eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

This is only a small portion of the code. I am wondering why my Display method
does not work, even though I am using the opengl library and have set the
native path.

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;  
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;  

public class Window  
{  
    public static void CreateWindow(int width, int height, String title)  
    {  
        Display.setTitle(title);  
        try  
        {  
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));  
            Display.create();  
            Keyboard.create();  
            Mouse.create();  
        }  
        catch (LWJGLException e)   
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:   
Display cannot be resolved  
Display cannot be resolved  
DisplayMode cannot be resolved to a type  
Display cannot be resolved  
Keyboard cannot be resolved  
Mouse cannot be resolved  
LWJGLException cannot be resolved to a type  

at com.base.engine.rendering.Window.CreateWindow(Window.java:14)  
at com.base.engine.core.CoreEngine.CreateWindow(CoreEngine.java:27)  
at com.base.game.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Comment: Could be because you're using LWJGL 3 where these classes doesn't exist anything.

Answer (score 0):

That looks a lot like something the eclipse compiler would produce in case you have compile errors in your code. And it also tells you what the error is.

My guess is that you are running it from within eclipse IDE and you have compile errors because you didn't include LWJGL in the eclipse library path. If you don't see any compile error and you are sure that LWJGL is included in the library path - try to rebuild the whole project (maybe some IDE cache didn't work correctly?).